# Magento: newsletter email address import for multi store setup?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a magento enterprise installation with 9 different Websites in it. I want to import newsletter subscribers in magento, but for different websites. Like US will have different subscribers and Canada will have different once.

I found this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-address-import.html but this simply adds all email addresses to Main Default websites, there is no way of assigning store/website.

I found this post as well: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7626/#t29973 where we can import newsletter subscribers, but here is also no way of assigning store/website id.

Can anyone help me to solve this, or please tell me if anyone knows about any script or extension which can do newsletter subscriber import in magento based on different websites/stores.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Newsletter module so you can select the country for which you want to send the newsletter. (in admin, add a new dropbox with all countries and rewrite the controller).